# OS X上のAtomエディタでキーバインドを設定し、ポップアップ辞書を表示させたい。

Tags: macos, atom-editor, key-mapping, os-x-key-bindings

Mac OS X では選択した文字列に対し、標準で辞書をポップアップ表示する機能があります。
1. 辞書を引く文字列を選択する。
2. ショートカットを入力（デフォルトはctrl-cmd-d）

Atomではキーバインドが独自の仕組みのため、上記操作ではポップアップされません。
そこで、下記URLを参考にkeycap.csonを変更し、マシンごと再起動を行って上記操作を行いましたがポップアップは表示されませんでした。
https://atom.io/docs/v0.196.0/behind-atom-keymaps-in-depth

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-cmd-d': 'native!'
```

設定の記述方法に誤解があるのでしょうか？

---

2015/11/01 編集：
設定値を以下で試すことで挙動が変わることを確認しました。
`native!`：ポップアップは表示されない。
`unset!`：ポップアップは最後の一単語で表示される。同じ操作でポップアップ表示されなくなる時がある。
　また、検索語は文末の単語や文字となってしまい、意図した検索ができない場合がある。

`abort!`：ポップアップは表示されない。
`unset! native!`：ポップアップは表示されない。

---

別の検証として以下を試しました。
`cmd-d`(検索して置換,find-and-replace:select-next)のバインディングを変更
`'atom-text-editor':`
`'.platform-darwin atom-text-editor':`
それぞれに同じ値を設定する。

`native!`：機能する。
`unset!`：機能しない。
`abort!`：機能しない。
`unset! native!`：機能する。

結果：`native!`を設定した時は既存のバインドは解除されないのでそのまま機能しているようです。
[image: binding]

---

(編集ここまで）

使用環境
- OS X El Capitan 10.11.1
- Atom 1.1.0

実行したいイメージ(Atomの代わりにSafariのテキストボックスで"Atom"を検索した例)
[image: 選択文字列にポップアップで辞書を引くイメージ]

---

2015/11/01 追記：
類似した機能を提供するパッケージに「dictionary」がありますが、こちらは辞書.appのウインドウを表示させる機能のため、少し煩雑になります。
https://atom.io/packages/dictionary

Comment: `native!` を `unset!` に変更するとどうなりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。 
試してみたところ、予期しない検索ワードですがポップアップ辞書が表示されました。
一定の条件下（文末に記号が入らない etc.）でファイル末尾の文字や単語を選択文字列にしているようです。

Comment: ターミナルから辞書.appを起動する方法を調べると以下のような記事に行き着きますがポップアップで表示している方は見つけられませんでした。

まず表示方法を調査する必要がありそうです。

参考：「辞書(Dictionary).appを使い倒そう」
http://sakito.jp/mac/dictionary.html
（ポップアップでなく辞書.appの別ウインドウとして表示する前提の記事です）

Comment: 確認ですが、Atom 上で `cmd-d` を入力すると何が起きますか？

Comment: `cmd−d`では設定されているfind-and-replace:select-nextが正しく実行されているようです。
選択した文字列を検索、置換できています。

Comment: 上手く行くかどうか分かりませんが、`cmd-d` も `unset!` するとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: もう一つ、Atom の source code をざっと眺めていて気付いたのですが、`abort!` という設定があります。`'ctrl-cmd-d': 'abort!'` も試してみて下さい。

Comment: `'atom-text-editor:':
  'ctrl-cmd-d': 'unset!'
  'cmd-d': 'unset!'` の認識であっていますか？ 再起動後試したのですが、挙動は変わりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。申し訳ありませんが上記`'atom-text-editor:'`に誤字がありました。 一度これまでの設定を見直して本文に編集し直したいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己回答になりますが、結論としてはAtom自体が該当機能を正しく実装している必要がありそうです。

OS標準機能と思っていたのは、辞書.appのウインドウで開く「辞書で調べる」コマンドであり、
ポップアップ表示を行うには、Cocoaアプリケーション側で`HIDictionaryWindowShow()`や`showDefinitionForAttributedString()`に選択文字列を渡して呼び出すコードを書くようです。
標準のコンポーネント（NSTextViewなど）は上記のコードを書かずに意図したポップアップさせる事ができたのでAtom独自のコンポーネントがポップアップ表示に影響していると考えます。

参照：
http://michitoshi.blogspot.jp/2011/03/pdfkitapp_17.html
http://blog.fenrir-inc.com/jp/2013/01/dict-on-mac.html

上記から設定値を変えるだけでは実現は難しそうだという結論です。
お付き合いいただき、ありがとうございました。

---

2015/11/02 補足：
Atomの開発元に該当するIssueがありました。
やはり独自に選択テキストを管理しているようで表示対応はエンハンス項目にラベリングされていました。
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/441#issuecomment-30604720